# azure arm templates "resource not defined" even though it is

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager

I am trying to reference an ip adress and get the following error:

```
Deployment template validation failed: 'The resource 'Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses/ip-xxxx-dev' is not defined in the template
```

My arm template consist of a few sections, this section is a deployment:

```
{
            "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
            "apiVersion": "2019-10-01",
            "name": "createK8s",
            "properties": {
                "mode": "Incremental",
                "template": 
                    see template example below
                ,
                "parameters": {
                    "IP-name": {
                        "value": "[parameters('IP-name')]"
                    }
                    "NSG-name": {
                        "value": "[parameters('NSG-name')]"
                    }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

In the template i define and try to use the ip adress:

```
{
            "apiVersion": "2019-02-01",
            "type": "Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses",
            "name": "[parameters('IP-name')]",
            "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
            "sku": {
                "name": "Standard"
            },
            "tags": {},
            "properties": {
                "publicIPAllocationMethod": "Static",
                "publicIPAddressVersion": "IPv4",
                "ipTags": []
            }
        },
```

In my network security gateway, i try to use it in the rules like this:

```
{
            "type": "Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups",
            "apiVersion": "2020-05-01",
            "name": "[parameters('NSG-name')]",
            "dependsOn": [ "[parameters('IP-name')]"],
            "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
            "properties": {
                "securityRules": [
                    {
                        "name": "XXXXXX-TCP-80-Internet",
                        "properties": {
                            "protocol": "Tcp",
                            "sourcePortRange": "*",
                            "destinationPortRange": "80",
                            "sourceAddressPrefix": "Internet",
                            "destinationAddressPrefix": "[reference(ResourceId('Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses',parameters('IP-name'))).ipAddress]",
                            "access": "Allow",
                            "priority": 500,
                            "direction": "Inbound",
                            "sourcePortRanges": [],
                            "destinationPortRanges": [],
                            "sourceAddressPrefixes": [],
                            "destinationAddressPrefixes": []
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "XXXXXX-TCP-443-Internet",
                        "properties": {
                            "protocol": "Tcp",
                            "sourcePortRange": "*",
                            "destinationPortRange": "443",
                            "sourceAddressPrefix": "Internet",
                            "destinationAddressPrefix": "[reference(ResourceId('Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses',parameters('IP-name'))).ipAddress]",
                            
                            "access": "Allow",
                            "priority": 501,
                            "direction": "Inbound",
                            "sourcePortRanges": [],
                            "destinationPortRanges": [],
                            "sourceAddressPrefixes": [],
                            "destinationAddressPrefixes": []
                        }
                    }
                   
                ]
            }
        }
```

I don't understand the error, per the documentation using resource id  would mean it should not be a problem if the resource is not defined in the template, and the resource is actually defined in the template. I tried a few variations, and all fail in the same way.
I also cleaned out the resource group, hoping that when the ip is actually deployed (i use incremental deployment) it would fix the problem, but

Comment: see documentation on reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/template-functions-resource?tabs=json#reference

Answer (score 0):

As per the documentation you have mentioned in the comment,

When referencing a resource that isn't deployed in the same template, provide the resource ID and apiVersion. For example:

```
"value": "[reference(resourceId('Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses', parameters('ipAddressName')), '2020-07-01')]"
```

Check [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/template-functions-resource?tabs=json#resource-name-or-identifier).

Comment: You are right i missed the schema :)
it removes the error but does not fix  my issue.
If i remove my resources and deploy from scratch the expression does not work as the resource is yet to be created.
If i reference by name (as i should be able to, deploying from the same template) i get back to my original error, that the reference is not valid.

Comment: Then you will have to use dependsOn https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/define-resource-dependency#dependson to resolve this error.

Comment: You mentioned the resources are in the same template - are they in the same deployment?  You can take a look at this to see if it helps: https://bmoore-msft.blog/2020/07/26/resource-not-found-dependson-is-not-working/ if not we'll probably need to see the entire template.